# How to pull data from gcp pubsub with the command line?

Tags: shell, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I know the command

```
gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull mySubscription --auto-ack
```

This command delivers a table with many other data. I want just the data.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can ask the message as JSON and then process it as JSON with JQ. But the content is Base64 encoded, so decode it.

The full line to do that

```
gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull mySubscription --format=json | jq -r .[].message.data | base64 -d
```

Comment: With some shells (e.g. zsh) you will need to quote the argument to jq. So: `jq - r '.[].message.data'`

Answer (score 3):

we can even skip the pipe into base64 like this

```
gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull mySubscription --format=json | jq -r '.[].message.data | @base64d'
```